# uwp c# pass additional parameter to an navigationview event handler while binding the event at runtime

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, arguments

I have a navigationview and I want to pass extra argument to selection_changed event

```
MUXC.NavigationView navigationview = new MUXC.NavigationView();
navigationview.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler((s, e) => Navigationview_SelectionChanged(s, e, param));
```

getting error for above code

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Eventhandler' to
> 'Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attaching events, there is usually no need to new an `EventHandler`, because the type of `NavigationView.SelectionChanged` is **TypedEventHandler**, direct assignment will cause the type to mismatch.

If you create a `SelectionChanged` event handle method, you can attach it like this:

```cs
var navigationview = new muxc.NavigationView();
navigationview.SelectionChanged += Navigationview_SelectionChanged;

private void Navigationview_SelectionChanged(muxc.NavigationView sender, muxc.NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

From your code, you seem to have created a method with three parameters. If you need to keep the `param`, then you need to perform some conversion.

```cs
navigationview.SelectionChanged += (_s, _e) =>
{
    Navigationview_SelectionChanged(_s, _e, param);
};
```